# Issue with NavController and custom providers on Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a navigation issue in Ionic 2.

If I want to navigate from a page to another page normally using `this.navCtrl.push(thePage);` I can do it. But if I inject another provider I have this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!
Error: No provider for NavController!
```

For example, this is my code with NavController. Without my custom provider it works normally:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

/**
 * Models
 */
import { Competition } from '../../models/competition';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-view-matches',
    templateUrl: 'view-matches.html',
})
export class ViewMatchesPage {

    private competitions: Competition[];

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private statusBar: StatusBar
    ) {}

    public ionViewWillEnter(): void {
        this.statusBar.hide();
    }

    public ionViewWillLeave(): void {
        this.statusBar.show();
    }

    /**
     * Navigation
     */
    public goBack(): void {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
}
```

But now if I inject my `CompetitionsProvider`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

/**
 * Models
 */
import { Competition } from '../../models/competition';

/**
 * Providers
 */
import { CompetitionProvider } from '../../mocks/providers/competition-provider';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-view-matches',
    templateUrl: 'view-matches.html',
})
export class ViewMatchesPage {

    private competitions: Competition[];

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private competitionProvider: CompetitionProvider
    ) {
        this.competitions = this.competitionProvider.getAll();
    }

    public ionViewWillEnter(): void {
        this.statusBar.hide();
    }

    public ionViewWillLeave(): void {
        this.statusBar.show();
    }

    /**
     * Navigation
     */
    public goBack(): void {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
}
```

I get this error when I want to enter to this page: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!
Error: No provider for NavController!`

Why? What does one thing has to do with the other?

**EDIT:**
Can it have something to do that I use a modal in a moment?
The navigation is: RootPage -> Modal -> Page -> Page (HERE IM HAVING THAT ERROR)

**EDIT 2:**
**CompetitionProvider:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Models
 */
import { Competition } from '../../models/competition';

/**
 * Providers
 */
import { UserProvider } from './user-provider';
import { CommentProvider } from './comment-provider';

@Injectable()
export class CompetitionProvider {

    private competitions: Competition[];

    constructor(
        private userProvider: UserProvider,
        private commentProvider: CommentProvider
    ) {

        /**
         * It would be better to directly call a partialPositionProvider.getAllById(1);
         * instead generate mock partial positions here. The same with comments.
         */
        this.competitions = [
            {
                id: 1,
                partialPositions: [
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/dinesh.jpg',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                        position: 1,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(4),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/richard1.png',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                        position: 4,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/peter.png',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                        position: 2,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/mock-photo.jpg',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(4),
                        position: 3,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(4),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(5),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                comments: this.commentProvider.getAll(),
                hiddenComments: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                partialPositions: [
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/dinesh.jpg',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                        position: 1,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/richard1.png',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                        position: 4,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/peter.png',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(3),
                        position: 2,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        photoURL: 'assets/img/mock-photo.jpg',
                        user: this.userProvider.findById(4),
                        position: 3,
                        votes: [
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(1),
                                date: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                user: this.userProvider.findById(2),
                                date: new Date()
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                comments: this.commentProvider.getAll(),
                hiddenComments: true
            }
        ];
    }

    public getAll(): Competition[] {
        return this.competitions;
    }

    public add(competition: Competition) {
      this.competitions.push(competition);
    }

    public delete(competition: Competition) {
      this.competitions.splice(this.competitions.indexOf(competition), 1);
    }
}
```

**In app.module:**

```
/**
 * Ionic Native Modules
 */
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

/**
 * Pages
 */
import { RankingsPage } from '../pages/rankings/rankings';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ViewCategoriesPage } from '../pages/view-categories/view-categories';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { OwnProfilePage } from '../pages/own-profile/own-profile';
import { OwnProfileGalleryPhotoPage } from '../pages/own-profile-gallery-photo/own-profile-gallery-photo';
import { ExternalUserProfilePage } from '../pages/external-user-profile/external-user-profile';
import { UserNavPanelPage } from '../pages/user-nav-panel/user-nav-panel';
import { InboxPage } from '../pages/inbox/inbox';
import { MedalsPage } from '../pages/medals/medals';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { UserFollowsPage } from '../pages/user-follows/user-follows';
import { FollowersPage } from '../pages/followers/followers';
import { FollowingPage } from '../pages/following/following';
import { SettingsOwnProfileNamePage } from '../pages/settings-own-profile-name/settings-own-profile-name';
import { NearUsersPage } from '../pages/near-users/near-users';
import { CompetitionPhotosPage } from '../pages/competition-photos/competition-photos';
import { ExpandProfilePhotoPage } from '../pages/expand-profile-photo/expand-profile-photo';
import { ViewMatchesPage } from '../pages/view-matches/view-matches';

/**
 * Repositories
 */
import { CategoriesRepository } from '../repositories/categories';

/**
 * Providers
 */
import { StylerProvider } from '../providers/styler/styler';
import { UserSettingsProvider } from '../providers/user-settings/user-settings';
import { ScrollBySectionProvider } from '../providers/scroll-by-section/scroll-by-section';
import { UserNavItemProvider } from '../providers/user-nav-item/user-nav-item';
import { AlertsProvider } from '../providers/alerts/alerts';
import { OwnProfileProvider } from '../providers/own-profile/own-profile';
import { UserProvider } from '../mocks/providers/user-provider';
import { CategoriesProvider } from '../providers/categories/categories';
import { CompetitionProvider } from '../mocks/providers/competition-provider';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        RankingsPage,
        HomePage,
        LoginPage,
        ViewCategoriesPage,
        SettingsPage,
        OwnProfilePage,
        ExternalUserProfilePage,
        UserNavPanelPage,
        InboxPage,
        MedalsPage,
        ContactPage,
        UserFollowsPage,
        FollowersPage,
        FollowingPage,
        SettingsOwnProfileNamePage,
        OwnProfileGalleryPhotoPage,
        NearUsersPage,
        CompetitionPhotosPage,
        ExpandProfilePhotoPage,
        ViewMatchesPage
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
            activator: 'highlight', //Pressing effect buttons
            iconMode: 'md',
            modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
            modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
            mode: 'md',
            pageTransition: 'md',
            swipeBackEnabled: true
        }),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
            name: '__mydb',
            driverOrder: ['sqlite', 'websql', 'indexeddb']
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        RankingsPage,
        HomePage,
        LoginPage,
        ViewCategoriesPage,
        SettingsPage,
        OwnProfilePage,
        ExternalUserProfilePage,
        UserNavPanelPage,
        InboxPage,
        MedalsPage,
        ContactPage,
        UserFollowsPage,
        FollowersPage,
        FollowingPage,
        SettingsOwnProfileNamePage,
        OwnProfileGalleryPhotoPage,
        NearUsersPage,
        CompetitionPhotosPage,
        ExpandProfilePhotoPage,
        ViewMatchesPage
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        ScreenOrientation,
        StylerProvider,
        UserSettingsProvider,
        ScrollBySectionProvider,
        UserNavItemProvider,
        AlertsProvider,
        AlertsProvider,
        OwnProfileProvider,
        UserProvider,
        Camera,
        CategoriesProvider,
        CategoriesRepository,
        CompetitionProvider
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you install `ionic-angular`?

Comment: Did you restart the live server and try?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Mmm is not it supposed to install when creating the project?

Comment: @Sampath I just tried but, it still failing

Comment: @IvanLencina, I don't know, but if you're not sure that it's installed, you can run the installation again, nothing bad will happen

Comment: Delete `node_modules` and try it again.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide  I ran ´npm install ionic-angular´ but nothing :/

Comment: @IvanLencina, try to restart your project

Comment: @Sampath  I'm on it

Comment: @Sampath  I still having the problem deleting and reinstalling node_modules.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide  Could you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: @IvanLencina, just close your terminal, open again and run `ng serve` or something like this, I don't know how you're running the project

Comment: @CommercialSuicide  I tried it. I'm running with $ionic serve --watch

Comment: Is this test project? Can you share it through public git repo?

Comment: Please show your code in `CompetitionProvider ` and the way you import it in app.module.ts

Comment: @Sampath Its in a private repo of the company where I work :/ 
Can it have something to do that I use a modal in a moment?
The navigation is: RootPage -> Modal -> Page -> Page (HERE IM HAVING THAT ERROR)

Comment: Very difficult to tell more about it without debugging the app. If you can create a sample working app on here: https://stackblitz.com/ hope we can see the issue.

Comment: @Sampath  Thank you, i didn't know this tool. I tried to recreate it, in a fairly limited way, and it works here. I do not know what's happening.  https://ionic-ybwqtg.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Sampath
Editor url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ybwqtg

App url: https://ionic-ybwqtg.stackblitz.io

Comment: You need to share the `project url`. We cannot see your project there.

Comment: I just solved it upgrading to 3.5.2 (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#352-2017-07-13)  thanks so much!

Comment: @IvanLencina could you please add that as an answer, so we can then close the issue? Thanks :)

Comment: Of course, @sebaferreras :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it upgrading from 3.4.2 to [3.5.2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#352-2017-07-13) step by step :)

After upgrading, I began to see unused injected dependencies warnings that were causing me problems. I deleted them and solved problem.